# Unable to save partitioned data in in iceberg format when using s3 and glue

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, aws-glue, apache-iceberg

Getting the following error-

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Incoming records violate the writer assumption that records are clustered by spec and by partition within each spec. Either cluster the incoming records or switch to fanout writers.
Encountered records that belong to already closed files:
partition 'year=2022/month=10/day=8/hour=12' in spec [
  1000: year: identity(24)
  1001: month: identity(25)
  1002: day: identity(26)
  1003: hour: identity(27)
]
        at org.apache.iceberg.io.ClusteredWriter.write(ClusteredWriter.java:96)
        at org.apache.iceberg.io.ClusteredDataWriter.write(ClusteredDataWriter.java:31)
        at org.apache.iceberg.spark.source.SparkWrite$PartitionedDataWriter.write(SparkWrite.java:758)
        at org.apache.iceberg.spark.source.SparkWrite$PartitionedDataWriter.write(SparkWrite.java:728)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.$anonfun$run$1(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:442)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1538)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:480)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.$anonfun$writeWithV2$2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:381)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is the query i am running on spark 3.3, with glue catalog and saving to s3. The iceberg version is 1.1.0 -

```
USING iceberg
PARTITIONED BY (year, month, day, hour)
AS SELECT * from data
```

But when I try to save the data without partitioning, it works without any problems -

```
CREATE TABLE my_catalog.test.iceberg_test
USING iceberg
PARTITIONED BY (year, month, day, hour)
AS SELECT * from data
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-writes/#writing-to-partitioned-tables), the data needs to be sorted before saving it -

> Iceberg requires the data to be sorted according to the partition spec per task (Spark partition) in prior to write against partitioned table.This applies both Writing with SQL and Writing with DataFrames.

So this is how I fixed the issue -

```
df = spark.read.orc("s3a://...")
df = df.sortWithinPartitions("year", "month", "day", "hour")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("data")
```

and then ran the partitioned sql query without any problem.

Comment: hi did you try to Insert(append) into existing partitioned table using above? I am getting the same error. I could fix by using sorting for Create table but Insert Into (append) still fails with same error

Comment: @nir no I did not. You can try asking for help on the iceberg Slack channel, that is where I found this solution

Comment: sorting the data before inserting was required only till Iceberg version 1.2.0 , in version 1.3.0 and higher it is no longer needed